# OSX start X11 server from command line

Tags: python, xquartz

I've downloaded and installed the Quartz package from here

http://xquartz.macosforge.org/landing/

I've also downloaded, installed and setup the vnc2flv Python package here

http://www.unixuser.org/~euske/python/vnc2flv/index.html#install

Now to run flvrec.py I believe I first need to start the X11 server, but haven't a clue how to do so from the OSX terminal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally the X server is started from the Finder; it should've been installed as X11.app. If you must start it from a terminal, use the `open` command, as described at http://osxdaily.com/2007/02/01/how-to-launch-gui-applications-from-the-terminal/

Comment: failed with error -600